# SQL CE vs Jet in winforms application

Tags: .net, winforms, sql-server-ce, jet

I have a legacy desktop application using JET for the database.  The application needs to be able to access the database file from a network drive.  Should I migrate the data access to SQL CE (or SQL Lite), or leave it in JET?
Maximum table row size is around 50000.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely shouldn't use SQL CE in this situation.  It doesn't allow multiple connections from a network share.  For details, and ways to avoid corruption, see [this page](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/jimw/archive/2007/02/18/46141.aspx).

SQLite would work in this situation.  Otherwise, you can always leave it in its current form, and use the [Office 2010 Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=ja&displaylang=en). Another option would be to use SQL Server Express.

Comment: I'd stay with Jet 4.0/DAO 3.6 as it comes with the OS.   The Office 2007/2010 database engine are one more dependency and item to install.

Comment: @Tony: Unless you need 64bit compatibility, in which case, Jet is not so great...

Comment: How does 64-bit Windows manage Active Directory? If it doesn't have a 64-bit version of Jet, what's it using? Or is AD on 64-bit Windows 32-bit?

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: No idea what they're using - though I'd suspect they may have just left it as a 32bit app...

Comment: Well, 64-bit Access 2010 obviously works with Jet MDBs, so there has to be some way to use Jet 4 files via 64-bit. It's not entirely clear to me whether A2007/A2010 actually use the ACE to access MDBs or if they switch over and use legacy Jet 4 (the reason for my suspicions on that are that an MDB created in A2007/A2010 still uses the DAO 3.6 reference -- yes, that's independent of the db engine version, but makes me wonder...), but I originally assumed ACE was handling interaction with Jet 4 files, and now wonder about it.

Answer (score 0):

50K records is quite easy for Jet so long as sorting and criteria fields are properly indexed.   Also one rule in the Access world is to keep a connection open at all times to improve performance if multiple users are using the database file.  I would assume this rule holds true in other environments.

If you have more than 15-25 users updating the data then I'd suggest going to a product such as SQL Server Express.  Of course if you stay with Jet 4.0/DAO 3.6 it's built into the Windows operating system since Windows 2000 so it doesn't need any dependencies.  SQL Server Express would require an install on a PC somewhere.